How to show Intel® Arc™ graphics "gpu shared memory" on ubuntu 24.04
Does anyone know how to show Intel® Arc™ graphics "gpu shared memory" on ubuntu 24.04?
I guess ubuntu 24.04's default gpu driver doesn't support this feature.
Is there any other Intel® Arc™ graphics driver for showing "gpu shared memory" on ubuntu 24.04?
Thx
Yen
